# Force empty query in search form when search fields are blank

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, filter, wildcard

I have created a search form which uses the fields within it to filter the contained subform. This works fine, except when the search fields are blank all records in the query show.

I would like for **users to see no records until they start to fill out the search criteria** (only when search fields are blank).

**Note:** Not all search criteria is required, so some fields may be blank when the form is used.

**Another Note:** I am NOT attempting to filter out blank fields within the query.

*** ***EDIT:*** I have a form, let's call it frmA. Within this form there is a subform, let's call it sfmB. The record source for sfmB is a query we'll call qryB.

**Sample query (which again, works as it should):**

```
SELECT FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD, FieldE
FROM tblA
WHERE (FieldA Like "*" & [Forms]![frmA]![FieldA] & "*") 
  AND (FieldB Like "*" & [Forms]![frmA]![FieldB] & "*") AND ...;
```

**Have tried:**

```
WHERE (IIf(IsNull([Forms]![frmA]![FieldA])=True, "", FieldA 
                  Like "*" & [Forms]![frmA]![FieldA] & "*"))...
```

**Also tried:**

```
WHERE (IIf([Forms]![frmA]![FieldA])="", "", FieldA 
           Like "*" & [Forms]![frmA]![FieldA] & "*")...
```

**Also tried:**

```
WHERE (IIf([Forms]![frmA]![FieldA])=Null, "", FieldA 
           Like "*" & [Forms]![frmA]![FieldA] & "*")...
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far so that people can see what needs improving.

Comment: @Parfait thanks for formatting the codebocks for me!
All: New edit -  removed backslash from sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason all records return is the empty form controls return *any* value as you are concatenating nothing with the wildcards so returns this search pattern `**` in the `LIKE` evaluation. As shown below with empty strings or nulls, this search pattern returns **all** records that have **any** non-empty character.

```
SELECT FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD, FieldE
FROM tblA
WHERE (FieldA Like "*" & '' & "*") 
  AND (FieldB Like "*" & '' & "*") AND ...;    

SELECT FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD, FieldE
FROM tblA
WHERE (FieldA Like "*" & NULL & "*") 
  AND (FieldB Like "*" & NULL & "*") AND ...;
```

To resolve, consider concatenating a character(s) that would not show up in you columns with the [`NZ()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) replacement. Below logic now will return all records by form search values as is. However, if form values are blank, `NZ()` substitutes with `~` and any records with this character in column will return. Assuming no tilda ever exists in that column, no records output.

```
SELECT FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD, FieldE
FROM tblA
WHERE (FieldA Like "*" & NZ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldA], '~') & "*") 
  AND (FieldB Like "*" & NZ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldB], '~') AND ...;
```

---

Turns out for full implementation the `NZ()` substitution value must be replaced dynamically. Hence, consider incorporating VBA per mutually exclusive conditions:

1. When all fields are empty, `NZ()` should use tilda (`~`).
2. When at least one field is non-empty, all remaining empty fields' `NZ()` should use the wildcard operator, asterisk (`*`).

```vb
Dim i As Integer, num_search_fields As Integer
Dim strSQL As String
Dim var As Variant

i = 0
num_search_fields = 5
' LOOP THROUGH ALL SEARCH FIELDS
For Each var in Array("FieldA", "FieldB", "FieldC", "FieldD", "FieldE")
    If IsNull(Forms("frmA").Controls(var).Value) Then
         i = i + 1
    End If
Next var

' CONDITIONALLY BUILD SQL
If i = num_search_fields Then
      strSQL = "SELECT FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD, FieldE" _
                 & " FROM tblA" _
                 & " WHERE (FieldA Like '*' & NZ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldA], '~') & '*')" _
                 & " AND (FieldB Like '*' & NZ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldB], '~') & '*')" _
                 & " AND (FieldC Like '*' & NZ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldC], '~') & '*')" _
                 & " AND (FieldD Like '*' & NZ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldD], '~') & '*')" _
                 & " AND (FieldE Like '*' & NZ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldE], '~') & '*')" 
Else
      strSQL = "SELECT FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD, FieldE" _
                 & " FROM tblA" _
                 & " WHERE (FieldA Like '*' & NZ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldA], '*') & '*')" _
                 & " AND (FieldB Like '*' & NZ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldB], '*') & '*')" _
                 & " AND (FieldC Like '*' & NZ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldC], '*') & '*')" _
                 & " AND (FieldD Like '*' & NZ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldD], '*') & '*')" _
                 & " AND (FieldE Like '*' & NZ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldE], '*') & '*')" 
End If

' ASSIGN SQL STRING TO SUBFORM RECORDSOURCE
Forms!frmA!subform.Form.RecordSource = strSQL
Forms!frmA!subform.Form.Requery
```

Comment: Thank you again for formatting my sample code to codeblock for me, but when this was done I had to edit it to remove the preceeding "\" which is not a part of my code, but was required for formatting to show the ampersand. I have updated the sample code to show "*" instead of "\\*"

Comment: Updated accordingly. But regardless of backslashes or not, the concept is same. This time search pattern is anywhere in the string, not between `\`.

Comment: My query is updated and this works perfectly. Thank you! \*dance of joy\*

Comment: One small thing... My users now have to fill in each field with an asterisk. Is it possible to keep the original feature of my query where if they filter by one form field, they won't have to add text to the other fields in order for the query to run properly.

Comment: Why are they filling in asterisk? Is that your design change because this solution does not require that.

Comment: What happens when implementing your solution is, if the field is blank the query searches for '~' (or whatever text) in that field. This forces the users to enter something in each of the search form fields. Originally they were able to search using one field and leave others blank. I was hoping to keep this feature.

Comment: Actually I see now. You actually need to dynamically change the subform's recordsource on the fly, specifically the `NZ()` substitution value. See update with VBA. When **all** search are empty, all `NZ()` should use `~`. When at least one field is non-empty, all `NZ()` should use wildcard, `*`.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE ([Forms]![frmA]![FieldA] Not Is Null) AND (FieldA Like "*" & [Forms]![frmA]![FieldA] & "*")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want no records returned when **all** search criteria are blank then you have to explicitly and separately test for this condition in your WHERE clause. Something like:

```
SELECT FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD, FieldE
FROM tblA
WHERE 
  NOT ( IsNull([Forms]![frmA]![FieldA]) 
        AND IsNull([Forms]![frmA]![FieldB]) 
        AND IsNull([Forms]![frmA]![FieldC]) 
        AND IsNull([Forms]![frmA]![FieldD]) 
        AND IsNull([Forms]![frmA]![FieldE]) )
  AND (FieldA Like "*" & [Forms]![frmA]![FieldA] & "*") 
  AND (FieldB Like "*" & [Forms]![frmA]![FieldB] & "*") AND ...;
```

So if all the search fields on frmA are null then the condition inside the `NOT (...)` brackets will be `TRUE`, the `NOT` will turn this into `FALSE` and so your whole `WHERE` clause will be `FALSE` and no rows will be returned. If any if the search fields has a value then inside the `NOT (...)` will be `FALSE`, the `NOT` will turn this `TRUE` and then any other conditions applied by the rest of your `WHERE` clause will come in to play.

**EDIT** - I have just re-read the answer from Parfait and actually I think that is a neater solution!

Comment: I am trying this solution as well... my guess is I'm missing something in translation, because the results are the same as my original query. Still working on it!